# Why does begin/end allow me to declare a variable partway through a SystemVerilog task?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm

I am trying to execute a sequence within the `run_phase()` task of a `uvm_test` derived class. I raise an objection at the start of the task; declare, create, and execute a sequence on a sequencer; drop the objection.

```
task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
  
  phase.raise_objections(this);
  
  uvm_sequence seq;
  seq = uvm_sequence::type_id::create("seq");
  seq.start(m_env.m_sequencer);
  
  phase.drop_objections(this);

endtask: run_phase
```

This gives me the error

`expecting an '=' or '<=' sign in an assignment`

referring to the statement `uvm_sequence seq`.

I know now that I can't declare a variable midway through a task unless I assign a value when I declare it. However, if I use `begin/end` statements, I can declare the sequence after I raise the objection, as such

```
task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
  
  phase.raise_objections(this);
  
  begin
    uvm_sequence seq;
    seq = uvm_sequence::type_id::create("seq");
    seq.start(m_env.m_sequencer);
  end
  
  phase.drop_objections(this);

endtask: run_phase
```

This code compiles fine. What is it about the `begin/end` block that allows me to declare a variable mid-task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 9.3.1 *Sequential blocks* shows the syntax for a `begin/end` block as:

```
begin [ : block_identifier ] { block_item_declaration } { statement_or_null }
end [ : block_identifier ]
```

After the `begin` keyword, you can add an optional block name followed by declarations of variables, if any.  These variables are local to the `begin` block.

This means that you can declare variables inside the `task` body after other procedural statements, like the call to `raise_objections`.

---

If you don't want to use `begin/end` there, you could place the `seq` declaration before the `raise_objections` call:

```
task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
  
  uvm_sequence seq;

  phase.raise_objections(this);
  
  seq = uvm_sequence::type_id::create("seq");
  seq.start(m_env.m_sequencer);
  
  phase.drop_objections(this);

endtask: run_phase
```